# ¿Cómo pasar el contenido de una variable PHP a Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo mover una variable PHP a una página en Javascript?.

Tengo esta variable `$temp` en PHP. Bueno, ahí es constante, pero será variable.

[image: Código PHP]

Moverla acá a Javascript. Les agradecería muchisimo su ayuda.

[image: Código Javascript]

Comment: La mejor solución para esto sería usar Ajax. En palabras sencillas, Ajax es como un puente entre el servidor (PHP) y el cliente (Javascript), que te permite enviar y traer datos de uno y otro lado, de forma transparente, sin tener que recargar la página y respetando la distribución de responsabilidades. Aquí mismo hay varias preguntas/respuestas sobre como funciona Ajax.

Comment: lo checare gracias

Comment: Otra opcion es: con Fetch API  https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/fetch-post-ajax-javascript.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de conseguirlo:

- Añades una etiqueta `<script>` en tu HTML dónde crearás la variable JavaScript a la cual le asignarás el valor de tu variable PHP:

```php
<script>
var $temp = "<?= $temp ?>";
</script>
```

- Añadirlo a una etiqueta HTML( por ejemplo, el body ) como atributo `data-*`:

```php
<body data-temp="<?= $temp ?>">
```

y luego rescatas el valor de ese atributo desde dónde lo vayas a usar:

```
$temp = document.querySelector('body').getAttribute('data-temp');
```

- Hay otras opciones( como enviarla en la query string del archivo JavaScript ) pero creo que estás son las más adecuadas según tu caso.

Comment: lo probare muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor, **no usen el código compartido en esta respuesta**. Sufre problemas de seguridad relacionados con [XSS (cross-site scripting)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 2):

Solo existe una forma segura de pasar el contenido de variables de PHP a Javascript en tiempo de generación del documento, y es haciendo uso de [`json_encode()`](https://php.net/es/json-encode).

JSON usa la representación nativa de datos de Javascript, por lo que la función agregará comillas a las variables que sean cadenas de caracteres, agregará corchetes a las matrices (arrays), llaves a las clases (o matrices de índices alfanuméricos), etc.

Un ejemplo de uso sería:

```
<?php
$temp = 500;
?><script>
/* Si defines la variable "temp1" antes de llamar a tu javascript: */
var temp1 = <?= json_encode($temp) ?>;
/* O si prefieres incluir el contenido de la variable directamente en "highTemps": */
highTemps = [ <?= json_encode($temp) ?>, 120, 90, 140, 640, 330 ];
</script>
```

Es **MUY IMPORTANTE** que cualquier variable, sobre todo las que no controlas o conoces de antemano su contenido, sean enviadas al documento HTML sin usar `json_encode()` ya que podrías sufrir problemas de seguridad relacionados con  [XSS (cross-site scripting)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Estos mismos problemas los podrías sufrir si agregas datos al documento, a un `dataset` por ejemplo, sin hacer uso de [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/es/htmlspecialchars):

```
<elemento data-temp="<?= htmlspecialchars($temp) ?>">...</elemento>
```

Si deseas consultar a PHP el valor actualizado de algo sin refrescar la página, entonces entran en juego [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) y [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch).